# Generally how long will Apple support submit apps with older Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it true that if you need your iOS 6 users to get your update, you cannot use Xcode 6 to submit updates, as Xcode 6 do not support iOS 6?

If that's true, how long will Apple generally allow us to submit with older version of Xcode (in this case Xcode 5.1.1)?

Thanks!

Comment: Xcode 6 lets you creates app that can support back to iOS 4.3. Why don't you think you can't support iOS 6?

Comment: I was using Xcode 6 betas and unable to download iOS 6 simulators. Btw where do I check the least supported version of any Xcode?

Comment: You need real devices to test your app with iOS 6.x or earlier.

Comment: is there a way to add iOS 6 sdk into Xcode 6?

Comment: @EthanLong, Yes just copy the files from the previous xcode version. Seek on stack for more infos

Comment: Why do you want to add more SDKs to Xcode 6? There is no need.

Answer (score 3):

Who said Xcode 6 does not support iOS6 Check in `Xcode6` deployment target there is by default appear 6.0.

[image]

Comment: Is this GM, 6.0.1? When I use beta I cannot find this and also cannot download iOS 6 simulators.

Comment: @EthanLong This is in any version of Xcode, include 6 GM and 6.0.1. This is on the Info tab for the project.

Comment: you can install ios7 simulator in Xcode6. else use device for testing. but you can set min iOS6 for you app from Deployment target that Xcode supported well. lets see with full Release Xcode6  :)